# Appending li to ul using appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have a images and i want to create a nav li for each image item..
Now i have this code

```
 var bigImages = $('#imagesList li img'); // gets the Big Images
```

Then i have created a ul with this id

```
<ul id="thumbsList">

    </ul>
```

Now using a loop i want to add a blank `<li> </li>` as equal to the big images in the array..

```
var rounds = document.getElementById('thumbsList');



for (var i = 0; i < bigImages.length; i++) {
        rounds.appendChild('<li> /li>');
    }
```

Now the console displays this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Please tell me where am i doing it wrong.thanks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Since you are using plain javascript, I will answer this in same:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bigImages.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("li"); //This is what you want
    rounds.appendChild(p);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/909/

Comment: Because appendChild expects a node which is what the error says. And you passed a string to it and that's why it was breaking

Comment: To do it with a string would be more like `rounds.innerHTML+=" <li> </li>";`